# Apache caching images

Tags: caching, apache2

Apache is caching images, and I have no idea where to look. I'm clearing the browser cache, and even trying a new browser that has never visited the site, and I get the old images.  After 15 minutes or so, the new images will load.  Apache will even report the correct (new) file size in the headers while sending an old file.

I have no idea where to look for this.  My server is Ubuntu 11.  This is only on my local development server, and it's frustrating to think my code is not working properly when this happens. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know the type of your image file (is it a NFS or SMB), but sometimes disabling `EnableSendfile` Directive in *Apache2* can ensure that because unlike what most folks think, apache DOES perform static-file caching, if file is of type `NSF`.

From [Apache Core Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#enablesendfile):

> This directive controls whether httpd may use the sendfile support from
>   the kernel to transmit file contents to the client. By default, when
>   the handling of a request requires no access to the data within a file
>   -- for example, when delivering a static file -- Apache uses sendfile to deliver the file contents without ever reading the file if the OS
>   supports it.

The solution is to add the following lines to your configuration file, `/etc/apache2/apache.conf`:

`EnableSendfile off`

Comment: Wow this is old. I did end up finding out that this was the problem, but it took quite a while. The files apache was trying to access were on a network drive.  (How virtualbox shares files with the host) This is where the caching was occurring.

Comment: @theHampster Cool that it fixed your issue, I was on this two days ago. Took ages to figure it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling caching for images explicitely:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.(gif)|(jpg)|(png)$" image_request
Header set Cache-Control "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" env=image_request
```

BTW, [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) is a nice plugin for Firefox, showing you all request/response headers. I found it a great help for debugging header data.

Comment: Thank you, now which of the several dozen config files should this go? (it's Ubuntu...)

Comment: Put in in `httpd.conf`, it's the main config file. Others are usually included from it via `Include ...`. You might also need to uncomment the line `LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so` for using the `Header` directive.

Comment: Sorry it took a while.  Too many tasks.....

1) those lines caused a 500 error.
2) those line tell the _browser_ not to cache images, right?  That's  not my problem.  I'm getting a response code of 200 AND a new file.  The problem is that the file does not match on the one on the server.

I've taken a hex editor and compared a jpeg image file to the file apache serves up, and they do not match.  I know it doesn't make any sense, but that's what going on.

Comment: 1) The config lines I wrote work fine here - did you ensure you're loading the modules required (mod_headers, mod_setenvif)?

Comment: 2) Caching will always be done by the browser (with different default strategies, varying by browser type). On the server side, you can only make Apache tell the browser not to cache things. When you look at the response headers, do the `Etag` headers differ between image versions?